# Exchange 2010 Mailbox Replication Service Error

Tags: exchange-2010, replication, logging

We are repetitively getting:

> The Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Replication service was unable to process jobs in a mailbox database.
>   Database: DB24
>
> Error: Couldn't find system mailbox 'SystemMailbox{fc55d672-c669-4cb7-bb3b-ef091441ec8c}' in Active Directory.

Server's been rebooted, it's already on SP3 and we know the mailbox isn't there as

```
Get-Mailbox -Arbitration | fl Name
```

doesn't show the mailbox in question.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If the mailbox doesn't exist you can create one:

> New-Mailbox -Arbitration -Name "SystemMailbox{fc55d672-c669-4cb7-bb3b-ef091441ec8c}" -UserPrincipalName "SystemMailbox{fc55d672-c669-4cb7-bb3b-ef091441ec8c}@yourdomain.com"

Make sure to replace `@yourdomain.com` with your UPN suffix.